# accessing multidimensional array with React js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I am working with a json api and I'm able to access the api and list out the first array with the map method but can't access anything beyond that.

```
{
"client_id": 1,
"client_name": "Moen, Hickle and Stehr",
"products": [ {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Ergonomic Cotton Keyboard",
    "product_asin": "cfq35yoyh64i",
    "product_image_url": "https://unsplash.it/310/676",
    "keywords": [ {
        "keyword_id": 1,
        "keyword_name": "nam",
        "keyword_country": "LV",
        "ranks": [ {
            "rank_id": 1,
            "rank_position": 214,
            "rank_page": 2,
            "rank_date": "2016-08-16"
        }, {
            "rank_id": 2,
            "rank_position": 82,
            "rank_page": 3,
            "rank_date": "2016-11-12"
        } ]
    } ]
 }]
}
```

How do I access the keywords and rank arrays? Is there a way to use the map method to nest in the prods function and output the keyword and ranking info?

```
var Product = React.createClass({

render: function() {

var prods = this.props.products.map(function(item, index){
  return(
      <ul key={index}>
        <li>{item.product_name}   </li>
        <li>{item.product_image_url}</li>
      </ul>      
    )
});

return (
  <div className="col-sm-12 compBlock">
    <div className="col-sm-6">
      <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        {prods}
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: what do you really want to do? Because you can get just do an inner map inside the map. Or just a for loop depending on what you need.

Comment: Yep you can just do another `.map` on `item` such as `item.keywords.map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this snippet should work.

I am using the `map` method within the high-level `map` call and assigning the results to a variable that I include in the high-level's return object

```js
const props = {
"client_id": 1,
"client_name": "Moen, Hickle and Stehr",
"products": [ {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Ergonomic Cotton Keyboard",
    "product_asin": "cfq35yoyh64i",
    "product_image_url": "https://unsplash.it/310/676",
    "keywords": [ {
        "keyword_id": 1,
        "keyword_name": "nam",
        "keyword_country": "LV",
        "ranks": [ {
            "rank_id": 1,
            "rank_position": 214,
            "rank_page": 2,
            "rank_date": "2016-08-16"
        }, {
            "rank_id": 2,
            "rank_position": 82,
            "rank_page": 3,
            "rank_date": "2016-11-12"
        } ]
    } ]
 }]
};

const prods = props.products.map((item, index) => {
  const keywords = item.keywords.map(cur => {
    return (
      <span>
        <li>{cur.keyword_name}</li>
        <li>{cur.keyword_country}</li>    
      </span>
    );
  });
  return(
      <ul key={index}>
        <li>{item.product_name}</li>
        <li>{item.product_image_url}</li>
        {keywords}
      </ul>                                       
    );
});

console.log(prods);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thanks so much for the snippet!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Would you please mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there a way to use the map method to nest in the prods function and output the keyword and ranking info?"

Answer: Yes.

You know that there is a property `keywords` that is an array of objects much like `this.props.products`.

To access, it you can use dot notation as you have with other properties within your existing `.map()` call.

To access, a property of an object on the array `keywords`, you can call `.map()` on it and access the property you want again with for notation:

```
var prods = this.props.products.map(function(item, index){
  // You already are referencing these:
  item.product_name
  item.product_image_url


  // To access keywords:
  item.keywords ( the keywords array )

  // Nested map on keywords can be called here also:
  item.keywords.map(function(current,index){
    // You can now access .ranks:
    current.ranks
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm adding item.keyword inside the existing map call but it's still not outputting the data [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Richcostello/Lb0o8o02/2/)

Comment: You'll need to ensure that you're using the `.map` results _within_ the return statement of the outer map